# one to one or one to zero relationship in mvc and entity framework with ApplicationUser table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I want to set one to one or one to zero relationship between Personal table and User table in MVC.
this is my personal class code:

```
 public class Personal
{
 #region Configuration
    internal class Configuration : System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.EntityTypeConfiguration<Personal>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {   
            HasRequired(current => current.ApplicationUser)
                .WithOptional(user => user.PersonalU)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
        }
    }
    #endregion Configuration
public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Key,ForeignKey("ApplicationUserID")]
    public string ApplicationUserID { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

and this is ApplicationUser code:

```
  public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
public virtual Personal PersonalU { get; set; }
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

but when I add controller with Personal table, error "Multiple object sets per type are not supported. The object sets 'ApplicationUsers' and 'Users' can both contain instances of type 'WebApplication1.Models.ApplicationUser'." is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd guess you're trying to put your `ApplicationUser` in a `DbContext` explicitly, but your `DbContext` might inherit from `IdentityDbContext`, which already has a db set for `IdentityUser`.

Don't do this:

```
public class MyAwesomeContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; } // this shouldn't exist 
    public DbSet<Personal> Personals { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Configuration());
    }
}
```

*I'd recommend renaming `Configuration` to `PersonalConfiguration` or something else, otherwise someone could think it's configuration from **Migrations**.*

Since `IdentityDbContext<>` already declares a `DbSet` for the `TUser` type you specify in `IdentityDbContext`, you just omit your `ApplicationUser` db set like this:

```
public class MyAwesomeContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<Personal> Personals { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); // don't forget this...
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Configuration());
    }
}
```

Make sure to put your `ApplicationUser` inside `IdentityDbContext<>` generic's type.

---

Also, your `Personal` class must have a key defined, which you can do in your `EntityTypeConfiguration` like this:

```
internal class Configuration : System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.EntityTypeConfiguration<Personal>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        HasKey(p => p.ApplicationUserID);

        HasRequired(current => current.ApplicationUser)
            .WithOptional(user => user.PersonalU)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    }
}
```

...and remove `[Key,ForeignKey("ApplicationUserID")]` from your class, since you're already using **fluent api**.

Comment: OK. I edit IdentityDbContext like above, but error "WebApplication1.Models.Personal: : EntityType 'Personal' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Personals: EntityType: EntitySet 'Personals' is based on type 'Personal' that has no keys defined." is done.

Comment: @user7553600 I edited my example, see if that helps.

Comment: @user7553600 also, take note the `OnModelCreating` inside the `DbContext`. It has to call `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);` in order to allow `IdentityDbContext` to make their own configurations.

Comment: @user7553600 take note my edits, you must put `HasKey(p => p.ApplicationUserID);` inside your `Configuration()`. Did you do that? Look my code samples....I tested here and it worked. Also, don't forget this line as well: `modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Configuration());`.

Comment: @user7553600 you're welcome, I'm glad I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
[Key,ForeignKey("ApplicationUserID")]
public string ApplicationUserID { get; set; }
public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
```

Set this

```
public string ApplicationUserID { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("ApplicationUserID")]
public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
```

Comment: in Register method: var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

Comment: ApplicationdbContext edited attention to Alisson user above.    OK. I edit IdentityDbContext like above, but error "WebApplication1.Models.Personal: : EntityType 'Personal' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType. Personals: EntityType: EntitySet 'Personals' is based on type 'Personal' that has no keys defined." is done.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to achieve this using EF 6.0-
Check if useful

```
public class Personal
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public string ApplicationUserID { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ApplicationUserID")]
        public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    }


public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [Key]
        public string ApplicationUserID { get; set; }
        public virtual Personal PersonalU { get; set; }
    }


protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Entity<Personal>()
                .HasKey(m => m.ApplicationUserID);

                builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .HasRequired(current => current.PersonalU)
                .WithOptional(user => user.ApplicationUser)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
}
```